# Puppeteer: No node found for selector - Login Modal in iframe

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to go to the login page, click on the username, and type in the username.

This is what I have so far:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 200 });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://fantasy.espn.com/basketball/team');
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.click('#did-ui-view > div > section > section > form > section > div:nth-child(1) > div > label > span.input-wrapper > input');
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.type('#did-ui-view > div > section > section > form > section > div:nth-child(1) > div > label > span.input-wrapper > input', 'hello', { delay: 100 });  
    await browser.close()
})();
```

I continue to get this error:

```
 Error: No node found for selector: #did-ui-view > div > section > section > form > section > div:nth-child(1) > div > label > span.input-wrapper > input
```

I don't get it; when I do, `document.querySelector` in the console with that path, I'm returned the input;  why is it not able to find that node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the element is in an iframe. so first you need to get the frame and then select the element from that frame. You would typically do:

```js
let iframeHandle = await page.$('#disneyid-iframe');
let frame = await iframeHandle.contentFrame();
let inputElement = await frame.waitForSelector('#did-ui-view > div > section > section > form > section > div:nth-child(1) > div > label > span.input-wrapper > input')
await inputElement.type('hello', { delay: 100 });
```

However, there is an issue with out-of-process frames, so you need to launch chromium with `--disable-features=site-per-process`. The following should work:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--disable-features=site-per-process']});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://fantasy.espn.com/basketball/team', {waitUntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded','networkidle0']});
await page.waitFor(5000);
let iframeHandle = await page.$('#disneyid-iframe');
let frame = await iframeHandle.contentFrame();
let inputElement = await frame.waitForSelector('#did-ui-view > div > section > section > form > section > div:nth-child(1) > div > label > span.input-wrapper > input')
await inputElement.type('hello', { delay: 100 });
```